# Mongoose - Find by array of ids, but retrieve limited results (1 for each id)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have my model called "Conversations", and my model "Messages", right now i want to retrieve all conversations with the last Message attached (only 1 message per conversation), so i filtered the conversationids and i queried the messages, but i'm not able to get this messages (last messages) for each conversation, thanks in advance.

```js
let conversations = await ConversationModel.find({});
const conversationIds = conversations.map(conversation => conversation._id)
//  ConversationIds is basically ["conversation1", "conversation2", "conversation3"]

//  Te problem is here, i want to attach the las message for each conversation, if i put limit(1)
//  i will get 1 record for all query, but i want the last message record for each conversation.
MessageModel.find({ _id: { "$in" : conversationIds} }, ...);
```

Comment: How do you define the last message for a conversation. Does it have a time, date-time feild in Messages documents to figure that out. It would greatly increase visiblity on the problem if you can provide sample documents in the question.  [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: By datetime, but basically i want retrieve 1 item for each id, for now any item is enough

Comment: Since I don't know how your documents look like, rather than posting an answer created a sample and an aggregation query. [See if that helps](https://mongoplayground.net/p/murYIiVW4hg). The idea is to sort by timestamp and then group to find the latest doc by `$first`.

Comment: Last question, how can i mark your last response as the solution?

Comment: If that worked for you, I ll post it as an answer which you can mark as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you man,works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From information gathered in comments; This is possible to achieve in a case where `MessageModel` documents contain a time-stamp to identify latest of them.

**Idea:** Filter messages based on `conversationIds` via [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), sort them by `timestamp` for the next stage where [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on conversation reference (lets say `conversation_id`) and pick latest of them by [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first) accumulator.

**Aggregation Query:** [playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/murYIiVW4hg)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      conversation_id: {
        $in: conversationIds
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      timestamp: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$conversation_id",
      latest_doc: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```